# Shipping Rate Calculating for given Country,State,Postcode and Price

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shipping-tax

I am trying on module for shipping rate calculation like ***Estimate Shipping.***

I have 4 text-boxes, One for country, one for state, one for postcode, last
one for Price. Here customer choose the state and country, enter the Postcode 
and Price.

After submit form i need to calculate shipping rate price for that 
provided data.

Here have only one shipping rate ***(Table rate)*** enabled.

Please any one help me

Thanks.